# Rundeck properties file has plain text passwords and I need them encrypted

Tags: rundeck

I can't have plain text passwords in a file on a system, how do I get Rundeck to use encryption on properties files or is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. On Rundeck (Rundeck OSS) you can encrypt the `realm.properties` file passwords, take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#propertyfileloginmodule).
2. On Process Automation (formerly "Rundeck Enterprise") you can encrypt any password following [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/encryptable-properties.html#rundeck-enterprise-config-property-encryption).

In a few words, it's possible only on Process Automation (formerly "Rundeck Enterprise").